# Orientation landscape not working properly in landscape

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7

`IOS 7` Orientation landscape  not working properly if it comes in landscape

This is demo run in landscape and potrait. so its working properly on portrait , but in landscape its not working properly. This is my demo project

Comment: [enter link description here][1]
IOS 7 Orientation landscape  no workign properly if i coming in landscape. Please help me

 This is demo run in landscape and potrait. so its working properly on potrait , but in landscape its not working properly. This is my demo project 

  [1]: https://www.facebook.com/download/638941606167445/Damu_Demo.zip

Comment: This is my link to demo project u can download from FB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.To start your application in landscape mode so that the status bar is in the appropriate position immediately, edit your Info.plist file to add the UIInterfaceOrientation key with the appropriate value `(UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight or UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)`, as shown in 2.

2: Starting your application in landscape mode

```
<key>UIInterfaceOrientation</key>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
```

3.Replace this code of nextView function- `[self.view insertSubview:self.secondView.view aboveSubview:self.view];`
with -`[self.view addSubView:self.secondView.view ];`

Comment: sorry boss that is requirement we need to use same code only insertsubview